# How to restore SQL Server database 

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, restore

I am playing with MySQL but reading this post before

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/creative-commons-data-dump-apr-11/.

I want to play with this data in SQL Server.

When I download them I found many `rar` files there. When I extract one of them, I found the `xml` file but I really do not know how I can restore them.

Can anyone can explain what I need to do to restore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this from shell command/command line

```
$ mysql -u [uname] -p[pass] [db_to_restore] < [backupfile.sql]
```

http://www.webcheatsheet.com/SQL/mysql_backup_restore.php